# What is the fan connector on a PC motherboard?

Tags: connector

Typically it is a three bare pin polarized connector, with power, ground and tacho connections. However, I am having difficulty finding it as a part. What is it called?

This is what I am trying to connect to
[image]

Comment: Sort of, but not quite, although I found the required info from a reference mentioned in it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fan#Connectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connectors used for computer fans such as the one pictured are 3-pin Molex KK 2.54mm pitch or compatible.

Newer motherboards use a 4-pin variant with a modified notch to allow for backward compatibility with the older 3-pin standard. Most PC fans still use a 3-pin connector though.

Answer (score 1):

That connector would be called something along the lines of "4 pin cable header" where it is important to know the connector pitch. I can't quite determine pitch from that picture but common industry standards are 2.0mm, 1.27mm, 1.25mm, 1.0mm.

Its mate would be called something like "4 pin x mm socket header". You should search for board-to-wire connectors. Likely, one of these will be the one:

http://www.molex.com/molex/products/group?key=wire_to_board_connectors&channel=PRODUCTS&langPref=english

Comment: And 2.54mm, which is the actual pitch on PC Fan headers.

Comment: At the serious risk of stating the obvious, 2.54mm = 0.1" or about 1/10 the width of a man's thumb.

Comment: @WesleyLee Still 2.54 today? I would find it too big to even consider for such an application. Or is that just old computers?

Comment: @Lundin -- yep, although I don't think its a bad thing that they didnt change the standard.